# .text() method returns [object Object] instead of text in cypress test

Tags: cypress

```
// should store text in "person" variable
const person = cy.get(' div.global-user-nav-menu > div > div > div > div.info-container > div.display-name').text()
```

I want to use these "person" variables as a function argument

```
SpaceView.assignTo(person)
```

Comment: Cypress commands by default will return a promise. If you want to assign the text to a variable, use the officially recommended approach https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Closures

Answer (score 6):

Cypress architecture works on promise chaining and you cannot break the chain and return values out of it... You have to chain the return values and act on it. It doesn't work on like selenium getText() method :)
So your below statement will not work.

```
const personName = cy.get(`div.global-user-nav-menu > div > div > div > div.info-container > div.display-name`).text();
SpaceView.assignTo(personName);
```

So you have to construct as below, in order to make it work

```
cy.get(`div.global-user-nav-menu > div > div > div > div.info-container > div.display-name`).then(element => {
      SpaceView.assignTo(element.text());
    });
```

(or)

```
    return cy.get(`div.global-user-nav-menu > div > div > div > div.info-container > div.display-name`).then(ele => {
      return ele.text()
    }).then(personName => {
      SpaceView.assignTo(personName);
    });
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. Both solutions  works

Comment: Good to hear that it helped you. Please vote up the answer so that it will reach to others whoever is looking for this... Cheers

Comment: I want to know How i can use within() in cypress?

Comment: Before asking for help, please look at the beautiful documentation that Cypress has to understand things.... https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Syntax

cy.get(loginForm).within(() => {
cy.get(button).click();})